# When I Deploy to Heroku the App Shell is There, But The Tabular Data is Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I developed a Book Review app locally, then pushed to bitbucket, and then deployed to Heroku. Everything seemed to go smoothly, but the Heroku version of the app is missing the actual data - like books, categories, users, etc. I did edit the gemfile as was suggested, so I'm wondering what I'm missing. What's necessary to actually import all my tabular data? Here's the gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.3'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.2'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Have you populated your production db?

Comment: Ah, this may be what I'm missing. How do I do that? Anyone have a link for me? Thanks.

Comment: I'll write an answer to clarify what you wrote

Answer (score 1):

So after doing a little more research I have learned that this kind of thing is common, and considered normal. Database structure is pushed to Heroku, but not the populating data itself. Other than using something like a seeds file to start with some initial records, it sounds like the actual populating data should be created on the production level.

Answer (score 0):

**Production DB**

As an update to your answer, you're dealing with different [*environments*](http://teotti.com/use-of-rails-environments/) (`production` for Heroku & `development` on your local system).

With different environments comes different databases (the data will be different), and as such, the reason you don't see any data in your Heroku db is because there is no data.

The two ways to resolve this are either:

- [`Seed`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) your production db
- Use the same db in `development` as in `production` (not recommended).

---

The simplest answer to your question is to use the `seeding` methodology in Rails:

```
#db/seeds.rb
Model.find_or_create_by attribute: "value"
```

This can then be invoked by running `rake db:seed` in your console.

Answer (score -1):

Run `db:migrate` and then `git add -A`, commit, etc

Comment: I did all of the above. And it pushed the shell of the app to Heroku. But data like users, books, categories, etc is still not there. I just again walked through the git status, git add ., git commit, git push heroku master steps. But still just the shell there, not the tabular data I created.